# SSH.NET : How to retrieve the status of file transfer from the SFTP server

Tags: c#, ssh, ftp, sftp, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET library and have written a simple method for ftp-ing files to a server as below:

```
    using (var client = new Renci.SshNet.SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
    {
        client.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to {0}", host);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass Payload error large files
            client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile));
        }
    }
```

How can I retrieve the status of transfer back from the server? I need to know if the files are being transferred successfully.

Can a TRY...CATCH work to retrieve the status back from the server?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your UploadFile line with this.  This provides a callback to the function you are calling.  The callback is in the brackets with o being a ulong.  Probably a percentage or number of bytes written.

```
        client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile), (o) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        });
```

**EDIT:**

The above is equivalent to this:

```
//I might be called multiple times during the upload process.
public void OnStatusUpdate(ulong bytesWritten)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bytesWritten);
}
...
    //later
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile), OnStatusUpdate);
```

They are calling YOUR function, and your function cannot be called without a value being passed to it.

Comment: I tried this but I don't get anything in the back bracket returned in o.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `Console.WriteLine(o);` line, does it get hit?  `o` has to be *something*.

Comment: It hits there but doesn't return a value.

Comment: Well...it's not "returning" a value but it MUST pass one....let me break this down for you a bit more.  editing...

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that could work.

1. Use the `Action<ulong> uploadCallback` parameter of `UploadFile(Stream input, string path, Action<ulong> uploadCallback)`. This can be used to check the number of bytes that been uploaded and could be compared with the size of the file you are sending.
2. Use `SftpFileSytemInformation GetStatus(string path)` on the path of the file you have uploaded, to check whether the file exists an again its size on disk.